# Power of prime ending with specified suffix

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I've came across a problem I've got no clue how to tackle.
Does such number exist, that it is a power of `7` and it ends with `654321` (gives `654321` modulo `10^6`)?

Comment: No, there isn't. We need to take $7^n$ with $n=4k$ in order to have a $1$ in the end. But then it ends with $01$.

Comment: True, thank you. And what about suffix 000001? Is there any general way of approaching this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Just compute it.  The powers of $7 \pmod {10^6}$ cycle with period some factor of $\phi(10^6)=4\cdot 5^5=400000$  If you don't find one within that number of cycles there isn't one. Once you find a cycle you are done.

Comment: Actually $\phi(10^6) = 400000$.  But the order of $7$ mod $10^6$ is just $5000$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Oops, I miscalculated badly by taking out all the $2$s, not just one.  Thanks.